# Помогите исправить текст. В чем здесь ошибка?

Tags: коммуникативные-требования

«Справиться с орфографическими и пунктуационными ошибками сравнительно легко. Значительно труднее справиться со стилистическими ошибками в письменных работах».

Answer (score 3):

**«Справиться с орфографическими и пунктуационными ошибками сравнительно легко. Значительно труднее справиться со стилистическими ошибками в письменных работах».**

Я считаю, что было бы логичнее "письменные работы" перенести в первое предложение. А то ведь звучит так, что орфографию можно и в устной речи исправить, а стилистику — только на письме.

Comment: Именно так. В первом предложении отсутствует необходимое уточнение.

Comment: Звучит парадоксально потрому, что первое возможно исключительно на письме, а во втором предложении просматривается противопоставление - из-за компактной группы "стилистическими ошибками в письменных работах". Исправить это можно и без переноса в первое предложение, достаточно _вдогонку_ вспомнить об общей для всего письменности чуть раньше: Значительно труднее **в письменных работах** справиться со стилистическими ошибками.

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно только найти ошибку - скорее всего, это неоправданный повтор слова справиться.

*Справиться с орфографическими и пунктуационными ошибками сравнительно легко. Значительно труднее - со стилистическими ошибками в письменных работах*.

Если нужна правка,лучше соединить в одно предложение:

*Справиться с орфографическими и пунктуационными ошибками в письменных работах сравнительно легко, значительно труднее - со стилистическими*